# how to use validation on textfield with below code (in swift)

Tags: validation, swift, email

```
 func isValidEmail(testStr:String) -> Bool {
    // println("validate calendar: \(testStr)")
    let emailRegEx = "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}"

    let emailTest = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegEx)
    return emailTest.evaluateWithObject(testStr)
}
```

Does anyone know how to validate an e-mail address in Swift? I found this code:

Comment: This code works. Use it like this for example: `let emailIsValid = isValidEmail("me@fake.com")`  *Now `emailIsValid` contains `true`*

Comment: for example ı created a txtEmail as a textfield  how to connect above code

Comment: Take the string from your text field and pass it to the function. Example for an NSTextField: `let emailIsValid = isValidEmail(myTextField.stringValue)`

Comment: thanks ericd  for your correction

Answer (score 0):

Assuming txtEmail is your UITextField:

```
var isValid = isValidEmail(txtEmail.text)
if isValid {
  // Do some things when email is valid
}
else {
  // Show error to user
}
```

Comment: @horizon the code will be wherever you need to check validation. If you're doing register or login it would be when the user clicks the button to login or register. Does this make sense?

Comment: func isValidEmail(testStr:String) -> Bool {
        // println("validate calendar: \(testStr)")
        let emailRegEx = "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}"
        
        let emailTest = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegEx)
       
    var isValid = isValidEmail(emailTxt.text)
    if isValid {
    // Do some things when email is valid
    println("true")
    }
    else {
    println("wrong")
    }
    return emailTest.evaluateWithObject(testStr)
    }

I code like that before viewDidLoad and also my textfield name is emailTxt but the code is not running

Comment: You can't do this logic in the viewDidLoad method. It needs to happen when the user completes an action like pushing a button.

Comment: you are right ı add to code login button .Can you send all code for me

Comment: @horizon I don't think you understand how things work on Stackoverflow. People are here to help, not write the program for you. Sorry